# Robot.txt only allow one.php and one folder

Tags: html

I work for a company and their web server is a mess. Several files I can't delete because they need to be access later. I dont want it to show in search engines I just found about robot.txt , very fascinating.

I just want it to allow my index.php and everything in my work/ folder

Is this correct?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Allow: /work
Allow: /http://mysite.com/index.php
Disallow: /
```

Comment: You are disallowing the whole site buy adding 'Disallow: /' so all of the above Allow statements are void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to allow `index.php` and `work` folder (and subpages of work). Crawlers will verify line per line if there is a match in pattern. If not it passes to the next one. In this case `Disallow: /` is the latest and will block crawling for all other not matched criteria.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /work
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Except that `Allow` is a non-standard extension without universal support.

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/yahoo-google-microsoft-clarify-robotstxt-support-14125

it's supported by yahoo, google and microsoft bing

Answer (score 0):

> To exclude all files except one
>
> This is currently a bit awkward, as there is no "Allow" field. The
>   easy way is to put all files to be disallowed into a separate
>   directory, say "stuff", and leave the one file in the level above this
>   directory:
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /~joe/stuff/
> ```
>
> Alternatively you can explicitly disallow all disallowed pages:
>
> ```
> User-agent: *
> Disallow: /~joe/junk.html
> Disallow: /~joe/foo.html
> Disallow: /~joe/bar.html
> ```

from http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: i can't move the files around, the company sort have old legacy links that need to be accessed